# How can you pull data from databse into a 2d array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am wondering if anyone can help. I am new to php, so apologies for my poor coding. I am trying to pull data from the database and for each lecturer I want to create a 2d array $lecturer1 [] [], lecturer2 [] [] etc and place each lecturer's id number in [0] [0]. I am a bit lost so any help would be really appreciated.

```
<?php
require ('mysqli_connect.php');

$lecturers_temp = array(array());
$i = 1;

$q2 = "SELECT `uninum` FROM `availabilityindex` ORDER BY `availibility`";

    $result2 = @mysqli_query($dbcon,$q2);

    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array ($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $lecturers = $row2['uninum']; 
            $lecturers_temp.$i = array(array());
            $lecturers_temp.$i [0] [0] = $row2["uninum"];
            $i++;

            echo $lecturers_temp.$i [0] [0];


    }


?>
```

Comment: Currently I am getting an array to string conversion error for $lecturers_temp.$i = array(array());                                 $lecturers_temp.$i [0] [0] = $row2["uninum"];                                           echo $lecturers_temp.$i [0] [0];

Comment: Dot operator is for string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a partial answer.....but I wonder if there is anyway I could create a separate array for each person, store their uninum in [0] [0] and leave the other part of the 2d array free for other data...eventually I want to have lecturer1 (A34567 (1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)

```
<?php
    require ('mysqli_connect.php');

    $lecturers_temp = array(array());
    $i = 0;

    $q2 = "SELECT `uninum` FROM `availabilityindex` ORDER BY `availibility`";

        $result2 = @mysqli_query($dbcon,$q2);

        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array ($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                $lecturers = $row2['uninum']; 
                $lecturers_temp = array(array());
                $lecturers_temp [$i] [0] = $row2["uninum"];


                echo $lecturers_temp [$i] [0] . "<BR><BR>";
                $i++;


        }


    ?>
```

Comment: Please combine your question, comment and answer into a single question. At the moment, it is unclear whether you are getting an error or you are trying to create separate arrays for each person. If you have two issues, please do two threads.

Comment: Okay, fair point JenB - Just to clarify, with the most recent code i posted I am no longer getting an error. The issue is that i want to create a separate array for each person and as a starting point I don't know their university ID numbers ('uninum'), so I have to pull them from the database. I want to have each person in a 2d array eg - $lecturer1 = (A4567 (1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1);